Null sets cannot be covered by intervals for sufficiently small $\epsilon$
I was trying the prove the following statement (Folland 1.5.30):

If $E\in\mathcal{L}$ and $m(E)\gt0$, for any $\alpha\lt1$ there is an open interval $I$ s.t. $m(E\cap I)\gt\alpha m(I)$.

The easiest proof I've figured out uses that $\forall~\epsilon\gt0~\exists~\{I_n\}\supset E$ a family of disjoint open intervals s.t. $m\big(\bigcup I_n\big)\lt m(E)+\epsilon$ and essentially $m\big(\bigcup I_n\big)\gt0$. If the latter is true for $m(E)\ge0$, then the hypothesis would be also be satisfied for $m(E)=0$, but I believe it is not since the problem specifies the strict inequality.
What do you think?
EDIT: The proof I'm talking about is Matematleta's post here.

Are you asking why this proof goes wrong when $m(E) = 0$? It's hard to say without seeing exactly how your proof goes. But I'm guessing that your proof ends up showing that $m(E) \le \alpha (m(E) + \epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ and concluding that this is absurd, or something along those lines. But this is only absurd if $m(E) > 0$. (I guess by ${I_n} \supset E$, you mean $E \subset \bigcup_n I_n$. It is still true that a null set can be approximated by such a family of open sets.)

@IzaakvanDongen I provided a link with the proof I'm referring to. Now that I'm thinking about it, that proof is wrong because $m(I_n)$ depends on $\epsilon$.  Is that right?

Yes, I agree that the dependence of $m(I_n)$ on $\epsilon$ is a problem in that proof. I think it's probably a "mental typo". The correct way to finish this proof is to reason that we have $m(E) \le \alpha \sum_n m(I_n) \le \alpha (m(E) + \epsilon)$, and take $\epsilon$ small enough to make that absurd. (and this step requires the assumption that $m(E) > 0$)

you can demonstrate that $$\sup_{I\text{ open interval}}\frac{m(E\cap I)}{m(I)} = 1.$$ To do that, you can use that the Lebesgue measure is regular and the fact that every open set can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals.

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks for your response! I would have thought $m(E)\le\sum m(I_n)$, and then $\epsilon>(1-\alpha)m(E)$, the RHS being strictly positive, and now with the correct proof the statement does not hold for $m(E)=0$.

Since the assertion is that there is an open interval $I$ such that $m(E\cap I) > \alpha.m(I)$, it follows immediately that $I$ is nonempty and any set $E$ with this property has $m(E)\geq m(E\cap I) >\alpha.m(I) >0$. Thus $m(E)>0$ is a necessary condition for the assertion to hold.
By definition of $m(E)$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a sequence $\{I_n(\epsilon): n \geq 1\}$ of open intervals such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1} I_n(\epsilon)$ and $m(E) \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} |I_n(\epsilon)| < m(E)+\epsilon$.
To make things concrete, if $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is given, then let $\epsilon_0 = m(E)\frac{1-\alpha}{2\alpha}>0$ (provided $m(E)>0$), so that the intervals $\{I_n(\epsilon_0): n \geq 1\}$ have the property that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1} I_n(\epsilon_0)$ and $m(E) \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} I_n(\epsilon_0)<m(E)+\epsilon_0$. For convenience, let us write $J_n = I_n(\epsilon_0)$ from now on.
But now if $m(E\cap J_n))<\alpha|J_n|$ for all $n \geq 1$ then we see that
$$
m(E) = m(E\cap \bigcup_{n \geq 1} J_n) \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} m(E\cap J_n) < \sum_{n \geq 1}\alpha.|J_n| = \alpha.(m(E)+\epsilon_0).
$$
But $\alpha(m(E)+\epsilon_0) = \frac{1+\alpha}{2}m(E)<m(E)$, hence we have a contradiction. Thus there must be some $n \geq 1$ with $m(E\cap J_n) > \alpha|J_n|$.
The particular choice of $\epsilon_0$ made above is not essential, however, in order to obtain a contradiction, $\epsilon_0$ must satisfy $\alpha.(m(E)+\epsilon_0)<m(E)$, so that $0<\epsilon_0<m(E)(\alpha^{-1}-1)$ and hence we must have $m(E)>0$.
Addendum: Perhaps it is worth phrasing the contradiction in terms of $\alpha$ instead of $\epsilon$: suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $m(E\cap I) <\alpha.m(I)$ for all intervals $I$. Then if $\{I_n: n\geq 1\}$ is a collection of intervals whose union contains $E$, we see that $\alpha^{-1}m(E\cap I_n) <m(I)$, and hence
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} m(I_n)>\alpha^{-1}\sum_{n \geq 1} m(E\cap I_n) \geq \alpha^{-1}m(E).
$$
But then since $\alpha^{-1}m(E)>m(E)$ (when $m(E)>0$) which contradicts the fact that $E$ is measurable.

Indeed, we have the results
$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{m(E\cap B(x,r))}{B(x,r)}=1,\quad x\in E.$$
Now you can always find this $x$ since $m(E)＞0$ and so the problem is proved.
